# Typed method in JpaRepository not returning correct type

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a method in a `JpaRepository` that is supposed to be returning a List of JPA entities:

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
    // ...
}

@Repository
public interface SomeOtherEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeOtherEntity, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select some big long native query", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<SomeEntity> getThings(String key);
}
```

When this query executes and I try to access the entries in the `List`, I get a `ClassCastException`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to my.package.SomeEntity
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at ...
```

When I debug, this is what I see:[image]

This seems like it's breaking strongly typed variables in Java. I didn't know this was possible. I can change my code to expect an Object array and to convert the Object array to entities but this seems like something I shouldn't have to do.

Comment: Can you paste the full native query (or at least the select part). Seems like jpa/spring-data can not resolve the return type from the query and defaults back to Object[]

Answer (score 0):

JPA does not seem to support specifying a result class for `@Query`. You can use `@NamedNativeQuery` or `EntityManager.createNativeQuery` to specify a result class.

See http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-native-queries/

Answer (score 0):

Your typed entity find method has to match the repository type. Here, you are declaring your repository entity to be `SomeOtherEntity`, but your find method `getThings` is returning (a list of) `SomeEntity`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [SqlResultSetMapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html). A good tutorial is: http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-basics/

Example code:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT o.id AS order_id, " +
        "o.quantity AS order_quantity, " +
        "o.item AS order_item, " +
        "i.name AS item_name, " +
    "FROM Order o, Item i " +
    "WHERE (order_quantity > 25) AND (order_item = i.id)",
"OrderResults");

@SqlResultSetMapping(name="OrderResults", 
    entities={ 
        @EntityResult(entityClass=com.acme.Order.class, fields={
            @FieldResult(name="id", column="order_id"),
            @FieldResult(name="quantity", column="order_quantity"), 
            @FieldResult(name="item", column="order_item")})},
    columns={
        @ColumnResult(name="item_name")}
)
```

Comment: Would you please extend the answer with the explanation about EntityManager? Some users might get confused reading the answer in the current state.